# Is there a way to pass additional arguments to a Converter in List.ConvertAll

Tags: c#, generics

Referencing [CovertAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=netframework-4.7.2).

It doesn't seem like there is a way, but I have a value that needs to be updated in each element of the list that is not part of the source list. I have many other places in this project using `.ConvertAll` but in this one place I need to pass in an additional parameter and was hoping to keep it consistent using `.ConvertAll`.

.i.e looking for something like this:
`lstNewStoreFrontOrders.ConvertAll(Order.ConvertToOrderDto(storeFront.Id))`

```
public static OrderHeaderImportDTO ConvertToOrderDto(Order storeFrontOrder, int storeFrontId)
{
    var orderHeader = new OrderHeaderImportDTO() {
        StatusId = ORDER_CREATED,
        StoreFrontId = storeFrontId,
        .....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use a lambda expression which captures `storeFront.Id`:

```
lstNewStoreFrontOrders.ConvertAll(order => Order.ConvertToOrderDto(order, storeFront.Id))
```

After all, `orders.ConvertAll(Foo)` is more or less just shorthand for `orders.ConvertAll(order => Foo(order))`.